# Creating a gridview to select records in ms access vba 2007

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, grid, vba, ms-access-2007

I am working on MS ACCESS 2007.The application I am working on has a dropdown box on one of its pages.The number of values in the dropdown box is so high that it goes beyond the screen size and it becomes difficult to see some values.This dropdown is to be converted into a grid now and the values should be made selectable.
Can anyone guide me how can I go about this?It's a complete new application to me.The data source is sql server 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListRows property of Combo-Boxes defaults to 16. Setting this value to a size less than the Form height is a better solution (IMO) than using a grid (datasheet in Access) since you will lose the Combo-Box's Auto-Complete functionality, which is of great benefit users who must select from very long lists.

Comment: The ListRows property of the combo-box I have is set to 40.I think ineed to set it to 20 may be so that a scroll bar is available.If I have understood right and this is the solution

Comment: Sadly though, my clients want a grid only.They now want a search textbox enabled on the grid to search for records.How to go about this one?

Comment: To create a "grid" on a form, you need to include a sub-form. Setup the Data Source as you did for the Combo-box. The sub-form will default to Datasheet view (grid). MS-Access includes Filtering mechanisms. You can either right-click on the field you wish to search or click the Filer icon.